# Trying to create a grouped bar chart but the legend isn't displaying every category

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to make a simple categorical barplot to show how many extra-marital affairs people had based on their happiness rating (x axis) and age group (in the legend/key). This is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

url = 'https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/AER/Affairs.csv'

affairs = pd.read_csv(url)
age_categorical = []
for row in affairs['age']:
    if 0<row<30:
        age_categorical.append("Under 30")
    elif 30<=row<=40:
        age_categorical.append("30 to 40 Years Old")
    elif 40<row<=55:
      age_categorical.append("41 to 55 years old")
    else:
      age_categorical.append("Older than 55")

affairs['age_categorical'] = age_categorical
# count number of affairs for each happiness rating 
affairs_subset = affairs.copy()
affairs_subset = affairs_subset[affairs_subset["affairs_dummy"] != 0]
affairs_rating = affairs_subset.groupby('rating').size()
# create dataframe table for plot
happiness = pd.DataFrame({
    'Happiness rating' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'Number of Affairees': [8, 33, 27, 48, 34]
})
# put in barplot
plot = sns.barplot(x = 'Happiness rating', y='Number of Affairees', hue=affairs['age_categorical'],data = happiness).set(title='Happiness and extra-marital affairs')
```

The resulting bar plot doesn't show all the categories in the legend.

[image]

Comment: You should be using `pd.cut` to create the categories, not a nasty for-loop

Comment: You're right, I use pd.cut now. For loops are very unneccessary for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Values need to be in the same dataframe so that the order is correct. Also you can just group by and create the table you are looking to plot.

```
affairs_subset = affairs_subset[affairs_subset["affairs"] != 0]
df = affairs_subset.groupby(['rating','age_categorical'])['affairs'].sum().reset_index()
sns.barplot(data=df, x="rating", y="affairs", hue="age_categorical")
```

[image]